# spring mvc javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: No validator could be found for type: java.lang.String

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc, hibernate-validator

I try to use the validators for the first time with Spring MVC and I always get the exception:

```
javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: No validator could be found for type: java.lang.String
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ConstraintTree.verifyResolveWasUnique(ConstraintTree.java:236)
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ConstraintTree.findMatchingValidatorClass(ConstraintTree.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ConstraintTree.getInitializedValidator(ConstraintTree.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.validator.metadata.MetaConstraint.validateConstraint(MetaConstraint.java:121)
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:334)
```

Here is my annoted class for validation:

```
public class AbstractEmployeDto implements Employable, Comparable<AbstractEmployeDto> {

private Set<AbstractClientDto> listeClients = new TreeSet<AbstractClientDto>();

private Long id;

@NotEmpty
private String nom;

@NotEmpty
private String prenom;

@DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy")
@Past
private String dateNaissance;

@Size(min=10)
private String telephone;

@Email
private String email;

private TypeEmploye typePersonne;

private String rue;

@Size(min=4, max=4)
private String npa;

getter and setter ...
```

And the controller with the annotation @valid:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveNew", method = RequestMethod.POST)  
    public ModelAndView saveNewEmploye(@ModelAttribute("command") @Valid AbstractEmployeDto employe,   
       BindingResult result) { 
        Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        if(result.hasErrors()){
            return new ModelAndView("/employes/add.html", model);  
        }
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Past` and `@DateTimeFormat` must be used on `Date` or `Calendar`
not a `String`. As bean validation doc says:

> The annotated element must be a date in the past. Now is defined as
>   the current time according to the virtual machine. The calendar used
>   if the compared type is of type Calendar is the calendar based on the
>   current timezone and the current locale.
>
> Supported types are: 
> **java.util.Date**
>    **java.util.Calendar**
>    null
>   elements are considered valid.

Porbably you need to use somehting like this:

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy")
@Past
private Date dateNaissance
```